# Microsoft Visio 2013 copy diagram into word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, copy-paste, microsoft-visio-2013

How do I insert all of Visio swimlanes into word document?

I am trying to copy from visio 2013 into word 2010. When I paste, the top left quadrant gets copied and nothing else.

Comment: Have you been over this MS KB yet? [How to paste or insert Visio drawings into other Office programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296826)

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly this is not answered correctly on Microsoft's "locked" forum threads. Most of the threads seem fixated on the wrong resolution monitor or some garbage like that. I do a lot of Visio with subsequent inserts into PowerPoint, Word, etc. This has happened to me when working on my laptop alone or with other screens. Sometimes it worked by itself and other times it did not.

When it doesn't work, there is good news! The document always appears cropped but it is in fact still there! Follow these steps to reveal it:

1. Select the Visio elements you wish to copy.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Go to Word, etc. and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>
4. Resize the pasted image so that it is small but still readable
5. Now Right Click on the copied image in Word and then click on the Crop Button in the pop-up menu
6. The Visio Image is now in "Crop-Mode". Grab one of the corners of it and expand it. The rest of the image will start to appear.
7. Resize as needed and done!

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the worksheet on Visio 2013

Ensure that nothing is selected (this includes the swimlanes),

Copy (use Ctrl + C or Right Click --> Copy Drawing)

Paste (any option you want)

You should not face any problems (in an ideal world)

Answer (score 0):

A stable way is to save the diagram as an image. I prefer to use the PNG format, but other formats are available too.

Simply `Save as ...` and select the image format from the file type drop down. An additional dialog will pop up asking you to select resolution and size. **Experiment** a little to see what suit your situation. As a quick default, I usually select a print resolution (more detail than a screen) with the default size.

If your drawing is large, the default print setting (600 dpi IIRC) will result in an image too large for Visio to handle. In these cases I select a default resolution (e.g. 300 dpi) that allows a reasonable sized image to be installed.

Once you have saved your image, you can insert it into your document as you would any other image.

Copying and pasting direct into Word will create a meta-image type. This means you can select various components ... or Word may automatically format them for you (unusual, but I have had it happen to me). Sometimes Word will not resize things properly and you will end up with compressed or overlapping parts. It was these experiences that led me to saving Visio diagrams as images. Never a problem since. An added bonus is that you can easily re-use the images in other applications and also attach to e-mails.

Answer (score -1):

select the content within Visio, right click navigate to Group select Ungroup. Then Paste into your word document.